# How to bake in Cycles without hidden objects affecting the bake

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

I have a clothing piece over a model and I am trying to bake the clothing piece in its location.  There is also a hidden object underneath the clothing, and i think this is affecting my bake.

Comment: Are you talking about baking materials/textures or physics simulations?

Comment: talking about materials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude an object from baking calculations by moving it to another layer from the object you are baking with <kbd>M</kbd>.  Then just uncheck the layer you have moved it to in the viewport footer before baking.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply: This is how i normally do it myself :) But my blender is giving strange errors and crashes when i move my mesh to another layer. i decided to put that question apart from this because else it would be 2 questions in 1. here is a link: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46478/no-valid-selected-objects-preventing-me-from-baking-material

Comment: @ChoCho  Well, AFAIK there is no other way.  This is how you exclude objects from baking.  You'll have to resolve the error so you can do it this way.

Comment: alright i figured that would be it. but its better to ask :)