# "No valid selected objects." - Preventing me from baking material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

When i move my mesh piece to another layer.
Blender either crashes on latest version.
or says this on older versions:  "No valid selected objects."

When i have it on the 1st layer however it does bake.
but its full of hidden objects that are interfering with my bake.
hence i am trying to bake on another layer.

Any idea?

Comment: Additionally, I found that you must have a closed mesh object as well. For most people this isn't relevant but it is what fixed it for me.

Comment: In my case I had to select the object in the top right corner list

Answer (score 11):

In the bake options see if "Selected to active" is ticked ON.

This is multiple object bakes.  Tick if off and try again.

make sure yout TEXT Image node is slected too

Comment: I needed to ensure Diffuse UV was selected in the SHADING mode, under Normal/Map node. For some reason this was blank for me, and I just needed to reselect the only available option.